# Flask Framework obtaining data from URL in request

Tags: python, flask

I have a form and when the user clicks submit it should go to this URL: "http://localhost:5000/CustomNames?fname=" via a GET request.

Then in Flask routing code I have:

```
@app.route('/CustomNames', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def CustomWords():
    words = request.args.get('fname')
    #words = session['fname']
    #words = request.form['fname']
    return render_template('test.html')
```

My question is how to I get that "fname" in the URL into a Python variable in my CustomWords function?

Those three "words =" lines are the things I have tried to get the data from the fname parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
words = request.args['fname']
```

Also, I was not importing request from the Flask framework which was generating an error.